# Tune a learner with the searchspace parameter setting

Tags: performance, mlr3

I am trying to tune a ranger learner with the searchspace parameter setting. The purpose is to find the optimal K (the number of input indicators, I uesd a filterpipe with setting *importance.filter.nfeat*) and D (the depth of each tree, i.e., *classif.ranger.max.depth*) by grid search. D's value should not be greater than the number of input indicators K. The values searched for D are then set proportionally to the input K: D ∈ {10%, 25%, 50%, 100%} ∗ K. Values of D ≤ 0 were rejected.
However, I am unfamiliar with writing *fuction* code within searchspace, thus the can not achieve the purpose (D is greater than K).

My question is:

1. How to set a parameter that is based on the other one in the searchspace? (I think it is different with the  [*depends*](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/optimization.html#searchspace-depends) metioned in mlr3 book)

Here is my code:

```
ranger = lrn("classif.ranger", importance = "impurity", predict_type = "prob", id = "ranger")

graph = po("filter", flt("importance"), filter.nfeat = 3) %>>% ranger %>>% po("threshold")
plot(graph)

graph_learner = GraphLearner$new(graph)

    searchspace = ps(
          importance.filter.nfeat = p_int(1,length(task$feature_names)),
          classif.ranger.max.depth = p_int(1,length(task$feature_names)),
          .extra_trafo = function(x, param_set) {x = graph_learner$param_set$importance.filter.nfeat * c(.1,.25,.50,1)})
    
    
    inst1 = TuningInstanceMultiCrit$new(
      task,
      learner = graph_learner,
      resampling = rsmp("cv"),
      measures = msrs(c("classif.ce","classif.bacc","classif.mcc")),
      terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 50), 
      search_space = searchspace
    )
    
    tuner = tnr("grid_search")
    
    # reduce logging output
    lgr:: get_logger("bbotk") $set_threshold("warn")
    
    # The tuning procedure may take some time:
    set.seed(1234)
    tuner$optimize(inst1)
    
    #Returns list with optimal configurations and estimated performance.
    inst1$result

   # We can plot the performance against the number of features. 
   #If we do so, we see the possible trade-off between sparsity and predictive performance:

     arx = as.data.table(inst$archive)
     ggplot(arx, aes(x = importance.filter.nfeat, y = classif.ce)) + geom_line()
```

2. How to know what indicators are uesd in the tuned model, for we only see the trade-off between sparsity and predictive performance, are they based on the importance rank?
   I also have tried the feature selection. In FS, I could get the optimal feature set. So what are the relationships betweet the *tuning nfeat* and *feature selection*? Which one is perfer in real partice?

```
# https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/posts/2020-09-14-mlr3fselect-basic/

resampling = rsmp("cv")
measure = msr("classif.mcc") 
terminator = trm("none")
ranger_lrn = lrn("classif.ranger", importance = "impurity", predict_type = "prob")

# 
instance =  FSelectInstanceSingleCrit$new(
  task = task,
  learner = ranger_lrn,
  resampling = resampling,
  measure = measure,
  terminator = terminator,
  store_models = TRUE)

# 
fselector = fs("rfe", recursive = FALSE)
set.seed(1234)
fselector$optimize(instance)

# 
as.data.table(instance$archive)

instance$result

instance$result_feature_set
instance$result_y

# set new feature_set
# task$select(instance$result_feature_set)
```

Comment: Any luck? I’m trying to do the first part, and also can’t figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer question 1?

[How to set specific values in `paradox`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62775936/how-to-set-specific-values-in-paradox)

Seems that you could simply set up your own data table as shown there, except remove rows where D>K, then use the design_points tuner.